# Declare an "unsigned T"

Tags: c++, templates, integer, unsigned

I want to use unsigned T in a template:

```
template<class T>
void signed2unsigned(const T* source, unsigned T* dest, size_t n)
    {
    do
        {
        intmax_t s=*source;
        s+=min(*source);

        *dest=s;

        ++dest;
        ++source;
        --n;
        }
    while(n!=0);
    }
```

This doesn't work, since unsigned without is expanded to unsigned int before the type T is taken into account. Is there a workaround other than just introduce U and write in documentation that U has to be an unsigned T?

Comment: How about [`std::make_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `std::make_unsigned<T>::type`

Comment: except that g++ (tdm64-1) 4.7.1 does not find it in <type_traits>
template<class T>
void signed2unsigned(const T* source, std::make_unsigned<T>::type* dest, size_t n)

and I have -std=c++11 on

gives

'std::make_unsigned<T>::type' is not a type

Comment: use a typedef std::make_unsigned<T>::type T_type

Comment: Eventhough it compiles, it actually breaks the idea of using a template since I cannot make a typedef as a template.

Comment: @user877329 You want to restrict the `dest` to an unsigned-like types (`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`)?

Comment: well I think this is a topic for a new question

Answer (score 11):

`std::make_unsigned<T>::type` is what you seem to be looking for.